# Close dialog, when pressed OK button on it

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

If the user clicks on a button, a dialog shows up, asking to input a string, and there's an 'OK' button on the same dialog, when the user presses that, the dialog should close. That's at least the plan, the problem is: after adding the eventhandler to the OK button, my application freezes, when the user would open the dialog.

```
addNewFamButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.newFamilyButton);
addNewFamButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.addNewFamily);
    dialog.SetTitle("Add new family to the list");
    dialog.Show();

    // Problem starts here:
    Button saveNewFamily = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialogButtonOK);
    saveNewFamily.Click += (object o, EventArgs ea) => { dialog.Dispose(); };                
};
```

I tried it with dialog.Cancel() too, but I got the same results. If I remove the last two lines, the dialog works, but obviously won't close.

**FIXED:** Thanks to user370305 for the simple solution:

```
Button saveNewFamily = dialog.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialogButtonOK);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **OK** button is part of `Dialog` view, so you have to find that view using your dialog object reference, something like, (I am not familiar with `xamarin` but this one gives you hint)

Change your line,

```
// Problem starts here:
Button saveNewFamily = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialogButtonOK);
```

with

```
Button saveNewFamily = dialog.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialogButtonOK);
```

Comment: That was the solution for my embarrassing problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
        // create an EditText for the dialog
        final EditText enteredText = new EditText(this);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Title of the dialog");
        builder.setView(enteredText);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
               // perform any operation you want
                enteredText.getText().toString());// get the text

              // other operations
                dialog.cancel();  // close the dialog

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
```